# Designing a client data table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

- What is the most important data I should gather from a client for a basic e-commerce site ?

  These are some of the data that comes to mind mind separated by sections (this is not a table design just yet as it could be altogether or separated but will go into that later):

  - Login credentials:

    ```
    email, password
    ```
  - Secret question data:

    ```
    secret question, secret question answer (or other method)
    ```
  - Client data:

    ```
    name, last name, birthday, address, city, state,
    country, postal code, phone, cellphone
    ```

  From the above I might be missing something but would appreciate if you could point out any other beneficial data that I could collect for the registration schema.

  **Should I also have a username and allow the user to pick which one he wants to use to login ? Does that bring any advantages ?**
- **What field type should I use that best describes each fields below ? Anything I have defined that I should change or consider ?**
- Should I use more then one table ?

  - why ? when ? any gains other then organization ?
  - What about when I need to retrieve it with inner or left joins wouldn't that be bad in a way ?

Here is an example of the design I was thinking as single table for now:

```
id int(X) PRIMARY auto increment
email varchar(X) UNIQUE
password_hash varchar(64)
password_salt varchar(6)
language tinyint(1)
time_offset varchar(5)
secret_question_id tinyint(3)
secret_question_answer varchar(X)
name varchar(X)
last_name varchar(X)
birthday datetime
address varchar(X)
address_complement(X)
city_id int(X)
city varchar(X)
state_id int(X)
state varchar(X)
country_id int(X)
postal_code int(X)
phone_regional_ext int(X)
phone int(X)
cellphone_regional_ext int(X)
cellphone int(X)
ts_register datetime
ts_last_update timestamp NULL on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
status tinyint(1)
```

Things marked with X I still need to check and see an acceptable size or correct field type.

As for state and state_id as well as city and city_id that is considering countries I don't have that kinda of data available to allow the users to input it by themselves or select one available with in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Security issues**
Note that the `secret question` undermines your whole security system. because you are storing the secret answer AND the secret question in the clear.

I recommend **not** using it. Email a reset password to the confirmed email address instead.

If you must use the mistaken notion of the secret question (the answer to which is an easy google on the user's Facebook page).
At least store the answer as:

```
answer_hash = SHA2(CONCAT(salt, lowercase(answer)),512)
```

> Should I also have a username and allow the user to pick which one he wants to use to login ? Does that bring any advantages ?

- As a user I prefer the email address.
- It is unique, I can never remember my username, but the email address is easy.
- The email address does double duty as communication link to the user.
- If you must have the email address, adding a username is just extra effort with no benefits.
- If a username must be unique, you're putting further burden on the user *(nobody wants to be named snowwhite45875 because snowwhite 1..45874 are already taken)*

> •Should I use more then one table ? •why ? when ? any gains other then organization ?

I don't think that's needed, 1 table will do fine for now and it will simplify your database.
If you want to split off data later into 2 tables, you can use a view to combine the tables.

> •What about when I need to retrieve it with inner or left joins wouldn't that be bad in a way ?

Optional data is retrieved using a left-join.
Data that links 1-to-1 is retrieved using an inner join.

If you join on primary keys it will not take a huge amount of time, but it will still take time.

Comment: `Note that the secret question undermines your whole security system. because you are storing the secret answer AND the secret question in the clear.` That is a very good point in fact I SHALL do that to be fairly honest with you I haven't looked so far ahead into the security and I don't even know if I will use the secret question yet. For resetting the password I was thinking of either sending a random password to the verified email or a code that would be use in the page as confirmation to allow the user to set a new password does that sound better ?

Comment: As for the username part I was thinking exactly the same the only beneficial thing I can thinking of having it would be a bit more security as the person would have to figure out the username and later the email passwords if they ever differ (as some or most users tend to use the same) `If you want to split off data later into 2 tables, you can use a view to combine the tables.` How would you split it like a profile and a login table linking the 2 by the user id ?

Comment: `If you join on primary keys it will not take a huge amount of time, but it will still take time.` right now I don't see this being an obstacle as I don't think I will hit a huge amount of access so soon that would make me worry about left-joins but I was kinda concerned in regards having too many of it due to splitting too many tables related to something for example on the above design having 3 tables  1 for user options, profile, login credentials.

Comment: @Guapo, `For resetting the password I was thinking of either sending a random password to the verified email or a code that would be use in the page as confirmation to allow the user to set a new password does that sound better`, a onetime password with a forced password reset sounds much better, that way no-one within your organisation will know the password.

Comment: `a onetime password with a forced password reset` how would that go ?

Comment: Simple generate a random string, store that in your db: `passhash = SHA2(CONCAT(salt,random_string),512), passreset = true` and force the user to change the password upon first login if `passreset = true`

Comment: AHHH got your point now ;) you meant about mailing the reset password with a one time password that forces the users to change it upon login, that's great idea ;) will start putting all these into a layout now and see what is the final out of it. Once again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Generally

1. i will spilt user acount details n user profile into 2 table.
2. i will use username by default cause i think it faster and easier to login.
3. you may consider adding gender field. location, age & gender data may help you market your product or service better.

Comment: Great point about gender totally forgot that, don't you think that having the address, country, state, postal code, birthday, excludes the need of age and location ? Any other toughs for the username usage other then just shortcut (just wondering)?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm not sure StackOverflow is the best place to get your requirements, but I'll add some items from my experience.

Most ecommerce systems recognize "delivery address" and "billing address" as separate data attributes.

Most ecommerce systems allow users to store multiple addresses, and retain history.

Most ecommerce systems store customer contact preferences - news letters, that sort a thing.

Most ecommerce systems store customer payment methods (though sensitive data such as credit card number is either left out or encrypted).

Most ecommerce systems store multiple payment methods, with history.

Some ecommerce systems store personalization data, such as product preferences, etc.

For most of those data items, you'd probably need to store them in separate tables, and join to them. You ask if there are any benefits other than "organisation" - for some concepts, it's almost impossible to store the required data without introducing new tables. For instance, the address data should live in a separate table if you want to store more than one delivery address for a given user.
This is not a bug - it's a feature. Joins are not "bad" - they consume only minimal resources (as long as you're joining on indexed fields).

Comment: Sorry about the Q not fitting here I was not sure where to ask it ;) but am open to suggestions. Thanks a lot for the points, I was indeed forgetting important things such as delivery address, billing address, delivery as gift and other points you made. I was not saying that join's are bad just that they can have a down side on performance and other things depending.